# How to derive column value based on occurrence of a phrase in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have input table as below

[image]

I want to have a derived column with the logic like

If for single value of COL1, if field COL2 has 'ABC' then DERIVED_COL will be filled with 'ABC_FIXED', if for a single value of COL2, if field COL@ does not have 'ABC', then DERIVED_COL will be filled with 'ABC_NONFIXED'.

Is this possible in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a self-join with a subset of same table with col2='ABC'. If join produces  result means ABC fixed else ABC  not fixed.

```
select orig.col1,orig.col2, 
case when abc.col2 is not null then 'ABC_FIXED' else 'ABC_NOTFIXED' end derived_col
from mytable orig
left join (select distinct col1, col2 from mytable where col2='ABC') abc
on abc.col1=orig.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using windowed function:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN COUNT_IF(COL2 = 'ABC') OVER(PARTITION BY COL1) > 0 
               THEN 'ABC_FIXED' ELSE 'ABC_NOTFIXED' 
          END AS DERIVED_COL
FROM tab;
```